# Is there an iPhone app that will map its connectivity to a Google Map?

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone

Our campus has wireless access areas which we would like a way to automatically map using some sort of Google Maps mashup in combination with a wireless device, preferable iPhone or iPod Touch.

The idea would be to walk the campus with the wireless device and as long as it stays connected, it would 'color' the map to indicate wireless coverage.  When it loses connectivity, obviously, it would not be able to 'color' the map at that location.

Does such an iPhone app exist?  Or for some other wireless device?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an iphone/ipod touch app but I do know that you can get a GPS device with a laptop and use something like netstumbler to at least get the data you want.

http://www.netstumbler.com/downloads/

Here is an older article about how to "wardrive" (which is essentially what you want to do but more like warwalking :D ): http://www.wikihow.com/War-Drive